# boost the score relative to term location in field elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Query

`{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"name:pi*"}}}`

Out put

```
hits: [
{
    _score: 1
    _source: {
        handle: PIXIES
        name: Pixies
    }
}
{
    _score: 1
    _source: {
        handle: twentyonepilots
        name: twenty one pilots
    }
}
{
    _score: 1
    _source: {
        handle: Antonio_Pinto
        name: Antonio Pinto
    }
}
{
    _score: 1
    _source: {
        handle: null
        name: Piano Tribute Players
    }
}
{
    _score: 1
    _source: {
        handle: null
        name: Los Pinguos
    }
}
{
    _score: 1
    _source: {
        handle: null
        name: Piyush Mishra & Bhupesh Singh
    }
}
{
    _score: 1
    _source: {
        handle: pinkfloyd
        name: Pink Floyd
    }
}]
```

If you look at the results it matches the terms in name with pi*, which is what I expect from the above query.

But how to write a query to sort results with term location(position index) in the field.
The results of that query should make `Piano Tribute Players`, `Pink Floyd` to pop up on the top of list. Since they begin with pi*

similar question on solr: [SOLR: Boosting based on location of search term in field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739104/solr-boosting-based-on-location-of-search-term-in-field)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scoring by term position in ElasticSearch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538766/scoring-by-term-position-in-elasticsearch)