# How to sort results based on term position in elasticsearch >= 5.5?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

Since `_index` is no longer available in Painless scripting, hence solutions which used to work via accessing term-offset from `_index` in `script_score` do not work any more such as one advised here: [Scoring by term position in ElasticSearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538766/scoring-by-term-position-in-elasticsearch).

What's the preferred way to do this now?

Thanks much for your help!

Comment: At the moment, this is the recommended solution: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/modules-scripting-engine.html. And, yeah, you'd have to do a bit code writing in Java for this.

Comment: Thanks @AndreiStefan! I will follow it up. However I thought that this will be a common enough requirement for a more straightforward solution.