# Scoring Elasticsearch by postion of query term in the indexed document

Tags: elasticsearch

Scoring Elasticsearch by postion of query term in the indexed document.

I mean if I have When I index say following documents :

doc 1: coconut red orange

doc 2: orange coconut apple

doc 3: coconut orange apple

I search for a term "coconut" and get I following result:

rank 1: coconut red orange

rank 2: orange coconut apple

rank 3: coconut orange apple

All the docs have  same score.

My disered output would have been :

coconut red orange

coconut orange apple

orange coconut apple

The term which I am searching for is at the start of the document needs to be ranked better than where it appears later.

Can someone help me how to get this done in Elasticsearch.

Thanks!

Comment: This previous QA might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538766/scoring-by-term-position-in-elasticsearch

Comment: This link I have check but couldn't reach a good conclusion how to do it.

Comment: The link provided provides a hack and considers only first term while ranking the docs. In our case the query  can have multiple terms/words.

Comment: I also don't see the same solution is working on > 6 version of elasticsearch.