# How to takes word order into account but does not require all searched words to exist in document for ElasticSearch match_phrase query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, match-phrase

Suppose that my index has two documents:

1. "get my money"
2. "my money get here"

When I do a regular match query for "get my money", both documents match correctly but they get equal scores. However, I want the order of words to be significant during scoring. In other words, I want "get my money" to have a higher score.

So I tried putting my match query inside the must clause of a bool query and included a match_phrase (with the same query string). This seems to score hits correctly until I do a search with "how do I get my money". In that case, match_phrase query doesn't seem to match, and the hits are returned with equal scores again.

How can I construct my index/query so that it takes word order into account but does not require all searched words to exist in document?

> Index mapping with test data

```
PUT test-index
{
  "mappings": {
      "properties" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "similarity": "boolean"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

```
POST test-index/_doc/
{
    "keyword" : "get my money"
}
POST test-index/_doc/
{
    "keyword" : "my money get here"
}
```

> Query "How do I get my money" - Doesn't work as needed

```
GET /test-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "keyword": "how do i get my money"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "keyword": {
              "query": "how do i get my money"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

> Results (Both documents scored same)

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 3.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test-index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6Xy8wXIB3NtI_ttPGBoV",
        "_score" : 3.0,
        "_source" : {
          "keyword" : "get my money"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test-index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6ny8wXIB3NtI_ttPGBpV",
        "_score" : 3.0,
        "_source" : {
          "keyword" : "my money get here"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

## Edit 1

As @gibbs suggested, let's remove the `"similarity": "boolean"`. A more simplified and focused issue presented below. We are trying to find an answer to this.

> Removed `"similarity": "boolean"`

```
PUT test-index
{
  "mappings": {
      "properties" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "text"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

```
POST test-index/_doc/
{
    "keyword": "get my money"
}
POST test-index/_doc/
{
    "keyword": "my money get here"
}
```

How to make this query return results? now it doesn't. Is it possible to return results if all searched words don't exist in a document when using `match_phrase`?

```
GET /test-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "keyword": {
              "query": "how do I get my money"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

## Edit 2

In our use case, we can't use BM25 (TF/IDF) because that messes up our results.

```
POST test-index/_doc
{
  "keyword": "get my money, claim, distribution, getting started"
}

POST test-index/_doc 
{
  "keyword": "my money get here"
}
```

```
GET /test-index/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "keyword": "how do I get my money"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

> Results

```
{
  "took" : 16,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.6156533,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test-index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "JnxCw3IB3NtI_ttPBjQv",
        "_score" : 0.6156533,
        "_source" : {
          "keyword" : "my money get here"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test-index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "x3xSw3IB3NtI_ttP1DUi",
        "_score" : 0.49206492,
        "_source" : {
          "keyword" : "get my money, claim, distribution, getting started"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In this scenario **my money get here** scores more than intended **get my money** because of TF/IDF. So, we can't have it where Score calculation will depend on the number of documents match, length of field, etc.

Sorry for the very long question. So, back to my original question **How can I construct my index/query so that it takes word order into account but does not require all searched words to exist in document?**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of your `similarity` parameter.

> A simple boolean similarity, which is used when full-text ranking is not needed and the score should only be based on whether the query terms match or not. Boolean similarity gives terms a score equal to their query boost

[Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/similarity.html)

You should use other similarity parameters (`BM25`) to get better scores.

I removed `similarity` parameter from your mapping and indexed same data. 
It used default `similarity` parameter.

Score is as follows.

```
{
    "took": 1069,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 2,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 0.5809142,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test-index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "WpaHwnIBa8oXh9OgX4Hb",
                "_score": 0.5809142,
                "_source": {
                    "keyword": "get my money"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "test-index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "W5aHwnIBa8oXh9OgeYG9",
                "_score": 0.5167642,
                "_source": {
                    "keyword": "my money get here"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, check now reply now.

Comment: Another data point on why I need to use `"similarity": "boolean"`


Without `"similarity": "boolean"`

```
POST test-index/_doc
{
    "keyword" : "get my money, claim, distribution, getting started"
}
POST test-index/_doc
{
    "keyword" : "my money get here"
}

GET /test-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "keyword": "how do i get my money"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```
In this scenario **my money get here** scores more than intended **get my money**.

Comment: No, I am not able to reproduce this. I still see that `get my money` have got more score. I think it is something to do with your data as well. Score calculation depends also on the number of documents match.

Comment: Updated my question, please take a look

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538766/scoring-by-term-position-in-elasticsearch) It will help you