# Elasticsearch / Elasticpress find ALL terms

Tags: wordpress, elasticsearch, search, elasticpress

I've been struggling to make my search work as expected, mainly because I don't know what kind of query I should make to fullfill my needs.

Essentially, what I am looking for, is that the results ideally would only include posts that include *every term*, but also keep fuzziness applied.

For example, if I look for the term '215 tires' it should bring results like:

- 215 tires
- 217 tires
- 225 tires
- 215 tire
- ...

I am in the process of creating an app and have been learning too many stuff, and Elasticsearch is just a part of it, but it is HUGE. I've done some testing but looks like I am missing something.

Based on my understanding, I would expect something like the following query to work:

```
$query = array(
  'bool' => array(
    'should' => array(
      array(
        'multi_match' => array(
        'query'     => '',
        'fields'    => $search_fields,
        'boost'     => apply_filters( 'ep_match_boost', 2, $search_fields, $args ),
        'fuzziness' => 1,
        'operator'  => 'and',
      ),
   ),
);
```

Obviously I am doing something wrong, because I am not getting the results I am expecting, eg if I search '215 tires' I am getting results also for '215' *alone*, without any mention of the word 'tires'.

I experimented a lot by the most famous *trial and error technique* but it bear no fruit. Any help?

Comment: What type datatype is stored in `$search_fields`?

Comment: @Nemo Not really sure, using default ElasticPress settings though. No matter the datatype, this query is based on the original query ElasticPress does, so I guess this is not the thing causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am relatively new to `ES`, but from the look of you question you want probably want to look at `terms`but [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) cannot be used with `text` `datatypes` as analyzers can sometime change words if you want a solution that is more robust then have a look at `score by word position`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27541692/8250795) is a question that was asked, I think it might solve your problem.